# android services explained to best?

Tags: android, android-service

Is there any article or book  with examples which explains Android Services at best? Android has too much overloaded service concept and I am finding very difficult differentiate between various services and there behavior.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer

### - [Android Service Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

### - [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let me google it for you... here it goes: [i was right there!](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)